# how to recover in lane from a bad bot lane start

Tags: league-of-legends

I play vayne as adc (silver, normal), so I already have a weak early game, but I do fine. Some games (more than I would like) the enemy gets a jump start with 2-3 even more kills ahead early. After that the lane is just lost. Can't farm (small aa range, no clear wave spells). The enemy lane just snowballs,  and it feels like there is nothing I can do.

What are some tips to recover in lane? And when the laning pahse is over should i go with the team to where the fights are or go where there is free farm?

Comment: Note that this is a much bigger issue with Vayne; her inability to recover from a poor start is the only thing that balances her enormous mid-/late-game strength.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Lane Freezing**

This is the most important thing to do when you have lost your lane.

**How to do it?**

Most important thing is, you have to deal as low damage as possible to the enemy minions. This does not mean you don't last hit at all. Deal the last hit when they are like 10-20 hp, this way you should be able to immobilise the enemy wave exactly where you want them to be. Preferably you should be freezing the lane just outside of your turret range for easier last hitting and easy escape into turret. Also, if the enemy minions are just outside turret range, tank some damage from them outside the turret range until your wave comes.

This requires a bit of practice, and it's not an easy thing to do. Precise timing when last hitting, etc requires practice and skills to achieve.

Once you've frozen the lane, just farm and farm until you have enough gold to come back into the game.

Another way to win back a lost lane is just to let the enemy take your tier 1 turret. Freezing lane at tier 2 turret is much easier and if by now the enemy started roaming, all the more better since you can freely farm. If they decided to stay in lane, ask for ganks - they're already overextending a lot, so a gank from the jungle usually won't go wrong unless they are both horribly fat. If they are horribly fat, hug tier 2 turret and just try to stall as long as possible, since diving a tier 2 turret before laning phase is over is equal to suicide. This method is especially effective on mid laners since while you let the enemy take your turret, you can roam other lanes to help as well.

There is another option, but this one's rather risky. Freeze your lane outside tier 1 turret, then ask for a 4 or 5-man gank. This will guarantee that they enemy laner will be killed or at least pressurised, as such, they won't try to engage on you every second they can. However, if your team makes a mistake, then it might also result in a free quadra or penta, which makes the situation from bad to un-salvagable.

Comment: thank you, it seems like a a sound advice. If am at tier2 farming and they start to roam, should I push the lane or continue to freeze it there? My instinct is to push the lane....

Comment: If you push they will come back, but if you keep freezing then your allies may get overwhelmed 5 v 4. Just like anything else in a strategy game, everything is situational. Also, just to be clear. To properly freeze the lane the damage from both sides must be EQUAL. If your enemy hits some minions a few times and you only last hit it will push instead of freeze so you must make the net damage difference as close to 0 as possible.

Comment: It also depends on the size of the minion waves as well. If they have a bigger wave then you will need to hit more to balance that out.

Comment: If u are horribly underfarm and underlvl then it might be a better idea to freeze the lane and call for other teammates to try not to group and fight. If u are doing fairly ok, maybe 1 lvl lower than the opponent than it would make more sense to help to put pressure on bot lane and at the same time actively contest the dragon